# Print each digit of a number on a new line in Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop

I have the following code written with the purpose of the program is for the user to input a number i.e. 123 and the program will output it as 1 2 3 vertically. No matter what I do, my program does it as 3 2 1. I need to use a loop in this program and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitsDisplay {
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = getInt("Give a non-negative integer: ");
        double backwards = 0;
        int reverse;
        int numOfDigits = numOfDigits(a);
        double place = Math.pow(10, numOfDigits);

        while (a != 0) {
            reverse = a % 10;
            backwards = backwards + place * reverse;
            System.out.println(reverse);
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }

    public static int getInt(String prompt) {
        int input;

        System.out.print(prompt);
        input = console.nextInt();

        return input;
    }

    public static int numOfDigits(int a) {
        int numOfD = (int)(Math.log10(a)) + 1;

        return numOfD;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reverse the reversed value

Your program is designed to reverse the digits. And it does. If you want to reverse them back, I suggest you append them to a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and then [`reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) that. Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (a != 0) {
    reverse = a % 10;
    sb.append(reverse).append(System.lineSeparator());
    backwards = backwards + place * reverse;
    a = a / 10;
}
System.out.print(sb.reverse());
```

#### Using a Regular Expression

Your algorithm could be simplified by using [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with a [*regular expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches and groups all digits of `a` and then replaces each digit with itself plus a new line. Something like,

```
int a = getInt("Give a non-negative integer: ");
System.out.println(String.valueOf(a).replaceAll("(\\d)",
            "$1" + System.lineSeparator()));
```